# Padding between Two UITextView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextview, constraints

I am working with the new constraints with iOS6. I have two UITextViews with a vertical spacing between them. Both UITextView's are dynamically populated the so the HEIGHT can be altered depending on the amount of content being populated.

What is happening is when to much data is loaded in the First UITextView it goes over the top of the second UITextView which is directly below it. I do have a constraint which is set between the two but it seems to ignore it. I have no code to show as it's on the storyboard.

Is there anyway to confine the vertical space between the to views no matter how much content is populated? Or has anyone come across this type of behaviour before?

Thanks in advance!

Jeremy

Comment: iOS works with absolute layout, you can set the top point of the second UITextView by getting height of the first UITextView and adding the padding you want.

Comment: Even if it's dynamic i.e. the content resizing the UITextView? I would have thought there was a way to limit that because of the limited realestate you have on the screen. Know of any examples? Or Tuts I could review?

Comment: UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, it has no limit on the contentSize.